# MobileESP for Joomla

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I can't seem to find a good answer to this anywhere. When using the "none / custom" mobile app service in the configuration for MobileESP in Joomla! it seems like you are required to enter the "device detection functions used".

Instead of entering every mobile device specifically (windows phone 7 os, ios, blackberry etc), isn't there a single setting that covers "all" mobile devices? I haven't been able to find that, but kind of expected it to exist. If not I'd be pretty disappointed...

I have not installed the Weever App, because the only thing I need is to redirect to a mobile site and support mobile devices to also view the full version (by adding a url parameter like "?full=1").

Any help will be appreciated! I have very little PHP experience, and even though I know you can add this functionality with a bit of PHP code in the header I'd rather just use a plugin for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you contacted the Weever folks yet? That would be the best place to start first.

I'm the founder and maintainer of the MobileESP code library. However, I'm not familiar with how Weever has integrated MobileESP support into their plugin.

If you were interested in MobileESP all by itself, then I would suggest you use one of the generic detection methods, depending on your goals. Specifically:

DetectIphoneTier(): Use this only if you want to detect modern touchscreen smartphones like iPhone, Android, Windows Phone, etc.

DetectMobileQuick(): Use this if you want *any* mobile phone, including old BlackBerry and Symbian smartphones as well as feature phones.

Links:

1. Weever on Joomla: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/mobile/mobile-apps/17890
2. MobileESP API reference: http://blog.mobileesp.com/?page_id=53

Comment: Thanks, I can't remember how I solved this but I appreciate your answer regardless!